# How to measure round trip time in Asterisk via console dial?

Tags: echo, delay, asterisk

I want to measure the round trip time of a call using the Playback() and Echo() Function in Asterisk. How can I do that? 
I'm thinking of something like this (just as example):

```
[test]
exten => 201,1,Answer()
same  => 2,Monitor(wav,CallRecord,b)   ;b => Start Record when call established
same  => 3,Dial(Local/202@test,10)
same  => 4,Playback(testfile)
same  => 5,StopMonitor()
same  => 6,Hangup()

exten => 202,1,Answer()
same  => 2,Echo()                      ;would be blocking here (thats my problem)
```

Is there a Solution to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have write custom app or open file in audacity and compare spikes of sound in left and right channel(in/out records)

Comment: Yes I already wrote a function using cross correlation. But my problem is to get the dialplan running... Echo() always blocks the dialplan so the Playback() and everything afterwards isn't executed. Now how can I make that non-blocking?

Comment: Echo on A playback on server B

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: No. It is out of scope of this question and require expert skill(or 2 hr of my time to give you example). Read books or hire expert.